# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.partitions.PartitionsLoader

Tags: aws-java-sdk

i alway get the error :

```html
[2018-02-05T09:04:14.682+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=26 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1517821454682] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[AddToOrderServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet AddToOrderServlet threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.partitions.PartitionsLoader
    at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionMetadataFactory.create(RegionMetadataFactory.java:30)
    at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils.initialize(RegionUtils.java:64)
    at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils.getRegionMetadata(RegionUtils.java:52)
    at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils.getRegion(RegionUtils.java:105)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.withRegion(AwsClientBuilder.java:239)
    at AddToOrderServlet.doPost(AddToOrderServlet.java:201)
```

And i have print the load lib in the running log:

```html
[2018-02-05T09:04:14.675+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=26 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1517821454675] [levelValue: 800] [[
  ******************]]

[2018-02-05T09:04:14.675+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=26 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1517821454675] [levelValue: 800] [[
  file:/home/ubuntu/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/BookStore/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.6.7.1.jar]]

[2018-02-05T09:04:14.675+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=26 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1517821454675] [levelValue: 800] [[
  file:/home/ubuntu/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.11.268.jar]]

[2018-02-05T09:04:14.675+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=26 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1517821454675] [levelValue: 800] [[
  file:/home/ubuntu/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.11.268.jar]]

[2018-02-05T09:04:14.678+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=26 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1517821454678] [levelValue: 800] [[
  DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.2]]
```

It seems like my lib is aws-java-sdk-1.11.268.jar and i even check that there is a class PartitionsLoader exists. 
The running environment is : glassfish4.1 and my jdk_version is :1.8.0_162.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I solve this problem by add all the related library into the jar rather than put the aws lib in the server and import them as an external library link.In case someone has meet the same problem can have a try.